# CAML Query to Sort list items based on Modified date

Tags: sorting, datetime, sharepoint

how can we sort sharepoint list items based on datetime field, i need sort to be done up to  milliseconds level.
curruntly i am using CAML Query as follows

`<OrderBy><FieldRef Name='Modified' Type='DateTime' IncludeTimeValue='TRUE' Ascending='False'/></OrderBy>`

Comment: every query from SharePoint has a few little delay depend on your list items and server performance. how much interval do you have in your delays in your queries?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For OrderBy CAML section should work fine the example below without Type and IncludeTimeValue attributes

```
<OrderBy>
   <FieldRef Name='Modified' Ascending='False'/>
</OrderBy>
```

[link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ms442728%28v=office.14%29.aspx)

Comment: hi VMA thnks for responding,
<OrderBy>
   <FieldRef Name='Modified' Ascending='False'/>
</OrderBy>
this query returning list items correctly, if we have minutes difference in 'Modified' field, but we have a situation that there may be multiple updates with in millisecionds, in such kind of scenario its not returning Excact sorted items.

Comment: [Here](http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/87124/formula-to-save-seconds-and-milliseconds-in-sharepoint-list-for-datetime-type-co/87133#87133) you can find out that in SharePoint Content Database Milliseconds for some reason excluded.